# Power Spectral Density excercise

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis

**Compute the power spectral density of $x(t) = \operatorname{sgn}(t)$**

Hint: $$\lim_{t\to\infty} t(\operatorname{sinc}(ft))^2 = \delta(t).$$

Please help me I have to solve this exercise urgently.

Thanks.